# MySql Dropdown filter select with NULL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, filter

I'm trying to build up a drop down filter system for a custom table. I have the following code but I can't seem to get it to work such that if one of the drops is not selected it still returns results based on the the selection of the second drop down:

```
<form method="POST"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
   <select name="bt_nbs_intervention">
     <option value=''>NbS intervention type</option>
     <option value="3">Protection</option>
     <option value="143">Restoration</option>
   </select>

  <select name="climate_change_impacts">
    <option value=''>Climate change impacts</option>
    <option value="15">Drought</option>
    <option value="12">Flood</option>
    <option value="25">Mangrove</option>
  </select>

 <input type='submit' value='Search'>
 </form>

<?php

if ($_POST['bt_nbs_intervention'] === '') {
$_POST['bt_nbs_intervention'] = null; 
}

if ($_POST['climate_change_impacts'] === '') {
$_POST['climate_change_impacts'] = null; 
}

$bt_nbs_intervention = (int)$_POST['bt_nbs_intervention'];
$cc_impact  = (int)$_POST['climate_change_impacts'];
$interventions = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("

SELECT ID, intervention_post_title
FROM wp_cpt_combined
WHERE (bt_nbs_intervention IS NULL OR bt_nbs_intervention = %d) AND 
(climate_change_impacts IS NULL OR climate_change_impacts = %d)", 
$bt_nbs_intervention, $cc_impact));

if($interventions)
  foreach ( $interventions as $intervention )
  {
   echo $intervention->intervention_post_title;
  }
else {
 echo "no results";
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do allow the user to select one or more of the select boxes to produce results. Such that if they only select Intervention type they get results or only Climate change impacts OR if they select both.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks
D

Comment: does it work when both dropdowns are selected?Did you try to do a `var_dump($wpdb->prepare("

SELECT ID, intervention_post_title
FROM wp_cpt_combined
WHERE (bt_nbs_intervention IS NULL OR bt_nbs_intervention = %d) AND 
(climate_change_impacts IS NULL OR climate_change_impacts = %d)", 
$bt_nbs_intervention, $cc_impact))` to see the actual query being performed?

Comment: Yes it does work when both drop downs are selected. Doing the var_dump places a 0 where bt_nbs_intervention = 0 or climage_change_impacts = 0, if the dropdowns are not selected. Which is why no results are produced I guess.

Comment: I added an answer, can you please look at the final version and check if it works out for you? What I did is that the where clauses are appended in an array and even values. Then we loop through the array and build the query in the loop itself.  If nothing is submitted we will not append any conditions to the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following please:

```
<form method="POST"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
  <select name="bt_nbs_intervention">
    <option value=''>NbS intervention type</option>
    <option value="3">Protection</option>
    <option value="143">Restoration</option>
  </select>

  <select name="climate_change_impacts">
    <option value=''>Climate change impacts</option>
    <option value="15">Drought</option>
    <option value="12">Flood</option>
    <option value="25">Mangrove</option>
  </select>

  <input type='submit' value='Search'>
</form>

<?php

$where = [];
$placeholders = [];    
if(!empty($_POST['bt_nbs_intervention'])){
  $where[] = 'bt_nbs_intervention = %d';
  $placeholders[] = (int)$_POST['bt_nbs_intervention'];
}

if(!empty($_POST['climate_change_impacts'])){
  $where[] = 'climate_change_impacts = %d';
  $placeholders[] = (int)$_POST['climate_change_impacts'];
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, intervention_post_title FROM wp_cpt_combined";

if(!empty($where)){
  $sql .= ' WHERE ';

  $i = 0;
  foreach($where as $clause){
    $sql .= $i == 0 ? $clause : ' AND ' . $clause;
    $i++;
  }

  $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $placeholders);
}

$interventions = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Wow. Nailed it. Thank you so much - really appreciate your help.

Comment: And as far as you know is this all ok in terms of preventing it SQL injection?

Comment: As long as you prepare the statements, you should not have any issue with SQL Injection. Please upvote and set as the right answer if it solved your issue :) thanks